# Query SQL Server CE to Listbox (Windows phone)

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-7, listbox, sql-server-ce

I have this code:

```
public void mostrar(ListBox medicinas_visual) {
    var query = from Medicamento in usuario_data.Current.Medicamento
                orderby Medicamento.id_med
                select new {Medicamento.id_med, Medicamento.nombre};

    medicinas_visual.ItemsSource = query.ToString();
}
```

And when execute the code returns: `{id_med = 1  nombre= Prepilon}` all string query, when I want that returns the values

Code XAML of my listbox

```
ListBox x:Name="medicinas_visual" Margin="0,56,0,4" FontFamily="/LI_health;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Helvetica S" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="166"/
```

Comment: Your select defines what is returned. If you want to change what your query returns then change your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this. This should work:
It Would Display id_med and nombre into Listbox

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="medicinas_visual" Margin="0,56,0,4" FontFamily="/LI_health;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Helvetica S" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="166">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding data}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

CS:

```
public void mostrar(ListBox medicinas_visual)
{
    List<Data> objList = new List<Data>();
    var query = from Medicamento in usuario_data.Current.Medicamento
                orderby Medicamento.id_med
                select Medicamento;
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        objList.Add(new Data(item.id_med, item.nombre));
    }
    medicinas_visual.ItemsSource = objList;
}

public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }

    public Data(){ }
    public Data(int id, string data)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I could fix it =D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to work XAML, but I see that you passing the listbox and after add the itemssource, you need passing the listbox using a references value, try this:

```
public void mostrar(ref ListBox medicinas_visual) {
    var query = from Medicamento in usuario_data.Current.Medicamento
                orderby Medicamento.id_med
                select new {Medicamento.id_med, Medicamento.nombre};

    medicinas_visual.ItemsSource = query.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Not works =(, the results is the same returns in the listbox {id_med = 1  nombre= Prepilon}

Comment: Mmm I'm confused, what exactly you need ?

Comment: I am making an application where I store the Id and the Name of a drug. What happens is that when I want show the ID and NAME in the listbox appears "{id_med = 1  nombre_med= Prepilon}" instead "1 Prepilon"

Answer (score 0):

Try add to the listbox the DisplayMemberPath tag in XAML or with c#:

```
listBox.DisplayMember = "nombre";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265158%28v=vs.95%29.aspx